# Как сделать space-between на react-native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Подскажите почему не работает space-between react-native

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему в консоли исключение?

Comment: так у вас и `flex` не работает. элементы же  в ряд должны быть